Removing a table without a unique index / constraint
CREATE TABLE "lemmings" 
(
    "id" bigserial,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "speeches" 
(
    "id" bigserial,
    "title" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "year" integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

No other tables exist in this schema.
The lemmings table has no unique indexes / constraints. This mean two lemmings can have the same name.
A lemming can give multiple speeches, and a speech can be given by multiple lemmings.
To clarify: a lemming can give more than one speech, and a speech can be given by more than one lemming.
Given the above, I think that the lemmings table is redundant, and the following steps should be taken:

Remove the lemmings table.
Add a lemming_names column to the speeches table.

Is my reasoning correct?

They can, but I'm not sure how useful a name would be in a dedicated table, verses inside of an array column. There isn't any concept of a unique lemming given a name. The lemming name seems to essentially be speech data.

Why are two lemmings with the same name two different lemmings and not just one lemming with two records?

Sounds like you shouldn't remove it, instead create a join table lemming_speech (lemming_id bigint REFERENCES lemmings (id), speech_id bigint REFERENCES speeches (id), PRIMARY KEY (lemming_id, speech_id)) An array column is both bad normalization and wouldn't work here due to lemming entities existing independently of speech.

@Frank Heikens That is essentially my point, that without any unique fields (excluding ID) a lemmings table would not be useful, as we couldn't distinguish between those two scenarios.

@Charlieface does the same logic apply to your suggestion? To my understanding the lemmings table will still have no uniqueness apart from the ID.

That's a separate issue: for that you can just add a unique constraint/index to name to enforce that. The surrogate id primary key is still useful because varchar(255) is very wide for a primary key, so it makes sense to keep name as a secondary unique key.

I have detailed in the question that no unique constraints exist for the lemmings table; unfortunately that is part of the scenario. Given this, I'm not sure a lemming entity can be identified using the name field, which is why I'm not sure a join table helps.

You don't understand what I am saying. I am not asking for a verbal description, I am asking where in the database I can see which individual lemming row belongs to which speech rows and vice versa? Without that information, the question is unclear.

No other tables exist, only the ones specified. I've added this to the question, thanks for the prompt.

My reasoning is that if a lemming cannot be accurately modelled then the relationship should not exist.

"Is my reasoning" You don't give any reasoning. What is it? PS It's redundant if it can be expressed as a query on the new base. PS But presumably every new or old base should be expressible as a query on the other DB & be appropriately constrained. PS The 2nd DB cannot have a lemming with no speeches. PS The 2nd DB can have a lemming with 2 names unless constrained in a way not possible declaratively in SQL, that its base is always the natural join of the 2 old bases, that FD id->name holds. It isn't in 2NF: that non-trivial FD is a proper subset of a CK determining a non-prime column.

@LaurenzAlbe Presumably speeches is rows where "lemming [id] made speech [title] in year [year]".

"no unique constraints exist for the lemmings table" In SQL PK means UNIQUE NOT NULL. PS constraint <> index

"if a lemming cannot be accurately modelled then the relationship should not exist" is not reasoning & it's not reasoning about why the table is redundant, it is a statement about your design goals/intentions & motivation for determining whether the table is redundant. PS "breaking 1NF" Not for any of the common senses of "1NF". "Essentially" A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly" or "falsely".

As you can’t (shouldn’t) have multiple values (lemming names) in a single column, you have model this with an intersection table? The fact that you only have a name attribute for lemmings doesn’t impact how you model M:M relationships

Presumably you mean, "multiple values (lemming names) in a single column" for a given lemming/id?
